# How to install brozot/Laravel-FCM in laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to install this package https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM on Laravel 6. But I'm facing following error

```
Using version ^1.2 for brozot/laravel-fcm
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.1
    - Conclusion: remove monolog/monolog 2.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.2.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.2.0].      
    - Installation request for brozot/laravel-fcm ^1.2 -> satisfiable by brozot/laravel-fcm[v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.2.3, v1.2.4, v1.2.5, v1.2.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install monolog/monolog 2.0.0
    - brozot/laravel-fcm v1.2.0 requires monolog/monolog ^1.19 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0, 1.24.0, 1.25.0, 1.25.1, 1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.19.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.20.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.21.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.22.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.22.1, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.23.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.24.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.25.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.25.1, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.x-dev, 2.0.0].
    - Installation request for monolog/monolog (locked at 2.0.0) -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[2.0.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I recently started with Laravel. Please ignore my mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the package dependencies listed at https://packagist.org/packages/brozot/laravel-fcm (and according to the message you've posted), this package requires Monolog in v1, but currently you have Monolog installed in v2.

To resolve this, you should either ask the package maintainer whether the package could support the most recent version of Monolog (which is already listed as a bug report in https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM/issues/152), or you downgrade your installed version to v1. But according to that bug report, I'd assume that the package is not compatible with Laravel 6 yet

Comment: Thanks. I tried to downgrade my monolog version to v 1.19. Now it is easily installed.